# Using multiple accounts on a SVN server

Tags: svn, authentication, accounts

Right now, I have two different accounts on the same SVN server.
Subversion saves the password for the last user, but seems to forget about the other one.

The problem is that I need to authentificate myself everytime I switch from one project to another.
Is there a way to avoid this?

By the way, I'm using the default svn client on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but how about using two different aliases/host names for the same server?

I imagine the SVN client would store different credentials because it thinks it's talking to a different server.

You'd have to set this up in your DNS or local hosts configuration. I can't think of any side effects right now, except in cases where you have to use a server name *within* the repository (e.g. with externals).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I think (not tried it) that you need to use different realms in your svn server.

See [client Credentials Caching](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache) in the redbook. It says you'll have several cache files - 1 for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SVN server offer access via different transports?

E.g. in our environments we commonly use svn+ssh and are able to specify different users in a way like this:

```
svn co svn+ssh://userid@server/project/...
```

Comment: I think it may work, but I can only access the server through https.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a second $HOME/.subversion config directory, and:

`svn --username second_user --config-dir second_dir cmd ...`